# MERN/Redux App: Image upload feature works in development, not production

Tags: reactjs, image, redux, file-upload, mern

**React/Node/Express app with Redux, connected to Mongo Atlas DB Cloud**

Hey all.  I created a basic portfolio application with full CRUD for an artist who wants to upload and display his art (called "Commissions" in my codebase).

I followed this article for how to upload an image to mongoose:

https://codeburst.io/image-uploading-using-react-and-node-to-get-the-images-up-c46ec11a7129

Basically, the strategy this article uses allows you to do 2 things when you upload an image:

1 - saves/sends the mongoose document to mongoDB (in my case, Mongo Atlas Cloud)

2 - saves the image in the local file directory within the app

It works locally.  I can upload as many files/images as I want, and it all gets displayed on the component, sent to mongo and saved in `app/uploads/`

Once I deployed the app to Heroku however, it doesn't allow me to upload any images.  And the images that were uploaded locally aren't displayed, only the other things like `commission.title`, `commission.description` etc

**CODE**

*Commission Model*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CommissionSchema = new Schema({
  imageName: {
    type: String,
    default: "none",
    required: true
  },
  imageData: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    maxlength: 22,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: false
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Commission = mongoose.model('commission', CommissionSchema);
```

*Upload Middleware via Multer*

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  };
};

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});

module.exports = upload;
```

*Post NEW Commission route*

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const upload = require('../../middleware/upload');
const Commission = require('../../models/Commission');

router.route('/').post(upload.single('imageData'), (req, res) => {
  const newCommission = new Commission({
    imageName: req.body.imageName,
    imageData: req.file.path,
    title: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
    price: req.body.price
  });
  newCommission.save()
    .then(commission => res.json(commission))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(`Create new commission failed: ${err}`));
});
```

*Redux Action for axios post*

```
export const addCommission = commission => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post('/commissions', commission, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: ADD_COMMISSION,
      payload: res.data
    }))
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({ type: ADD_COMMISSION_FAIL });
    });  
  axios
    .get('/commissions')
    .then(res => dispatch({
      type: GET_COMMISSIONS,
      payload: res.data
    }));
};
```

*Form Component (relevant code denoted with <~~ arrows)*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Col,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button
} from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addCommission } from '../../actions/commissionActions';     <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import ImagePreview from '../../images/ImagePreview.png';

class NewCommissionForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleImageChange = this.handleImageChange.bind(this);     <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      title: "",
      description: "",
      price: "",
      image: ImagePreview,
      redirectToCommissions: false
    };
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if(this.state.redirectToCommissions) {
      this.setState({
        redirectToCommissions: false
      });
    };
  };

  static propTypes = {
    addCommission: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleImageChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      image: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])     <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    });
  };

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let imageFormObj = {};                                                  <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    imageFormObj = new FormData();                                          <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    imageFormObj.append("imageName", "multer-image-" + Date.now());         <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    imageFormObj.append("imageData", e.target.elements.image.files[0]);     <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    imageFormObj.append("title", this.state.title);                         <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    imageFormObj.append("description", this.state.description);             <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    imageFormObj.append("price", this.state.price);                         <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
    this.props.addCommission(imageFormObj);                                 <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~

    this.setState({
      title: "",
      description: "",
      price: "",
      image: ImagePreview,
      redirectToCommissions: true
    })
  };

  render() {
    const redirectToCommissions = this.state.redirectToCommissions;
    const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.user;
    
    if(!isAuthenticated) {
      return (
        <h1 style={styles.accessDenied}>
          You don't have access to this page
        </h1>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Form style={styles.container} autoFocus={false} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <h1 style={styles.title}>Upload a new Commission</h1>
            
            <FormGroup row>
              <Label for="title" style={styles.labelText} sm={2}>Title</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="title"
                  id="title"
                  maxLength="22"
                  autoFocus
                  required
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.title}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
  
            <FormGroup row>
              <Label for="description" style={styles.labelText} sm={2}>Description</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input
                  type="textarea"
                  name="description"
                  id="description"
                  required
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.description}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
  
            <FormGroup row>
              <Label for="price" style={styles.labelText} sm={2}>Price</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input
                  type="number"
                  name="price"
                  id="price"
                  min={0}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  value={this.state.price}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>

            <FormGroup row>
              <Label for="image" style={styles.labelText} sm={2}>Image</Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input
                  type="file"
                  name="image"
                  id="image"
                  required
                  onChange={e => this.handleImageChange(e)}     <~~<~~<~~     <~~<~~<~~
                />
                <img
                  src={this.state.image}
                  alt="Commission Preview"
                  style={styles.imagePreview}
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
  
            <FormGroup row>
              <Col sm={2}>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Button outline block color="info" style={styles.submitButton}>Submit</Button>
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>
          { redirectToCommissions ? <Redirect to="/" /> : null }
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
};

const styles = {
  container: {
    paddingLeft: '5%',
    paddingRight: '5%'
  },
  title: {
    paddingBottom: 50,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  labelText: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textShadow: '2px 2px 4px black'
  },
  submitContainer: {
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingLeft: 'auto',
    paddingRight: 'auto',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  submitButton: {
    fontSize: '1.2em',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: 'white'
  },
  accessDenied: {
    textAlign:'center',
    paddingTop:50,
    paddingBottom:50
  },
  imagePreview: {
    marginTop: 15,
    width: 300,
    height: 300
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  commissions: state.commission.commissions,
  loading: state.commission.loading,
  user: state.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {addCommission})(NewCommissionForm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by being a stalker and finding the article author and contacting him.

- Upload a temporary image LOCALLY (updates the root/uploads/ directory with the image file)
- Save and commit/push to Git
- Deploy to Heroku

And that's all.  When I deployed the app, I cleaned out the /uploads/ folder (since I didn't want the test images I toyed with locally to be on the actual site).

This for some reason caused the feature to not work in production.  Perhaps Heroku ignores or clears the directory when it's empty.

However, deploying it with a file in the directory allows the feature to work as intended.